# Is there a way to force Vue to create empty attribute with "v-bind:" if it's bound to empty value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vee-validate

I'm using vee-validate. It must have value attribute to validate it. But if I'll bind it like this: `:value="formdata[name]"`then it works only when the string value inside is not empty. But it is empty initially. In run-time that value attribute is absent. I can do it like this `value=""` and change the value with my custom js functions but I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: "But it is empty" what do you mean, is it `null` `undefined` or `""` ?

Comment: If you are getting an error, please provide the error that you are getting.